# Android one of my text views has gone missing?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, tablelayout, multiple-instances, cells

I've been playing with the table layout for Android and have been attempting to programatically place 2 textviews inside of the same cell. I did some research on this subject and found that i need to use a layout in order to add more than one element to the same cell.

I have done this using RelatvieLayout but for some reason some of my textviews has now gone missing. Does anyone know why??

Heres my code:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout1.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); //(left, top, right, bottom)
layout1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout2.setMargins(50, 50, 0, 0); //(left, top, right, bottom)
layout2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

t1.setLayoutParams(layout1);
t2.setLayoutParams(layout2);

relativeLayout.addView(t1);
relativeLayout.addView(t2);

row.addView(relativeLayout);

tableView.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Heres my layout code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/ourTable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="7.64" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: could you show a screenshot.

Comment: put your layout code here

Comment: Basically the t1 text view is not being displayed

Comment: problem might be u have been using CenterInParent attribute for two layouts ,so two layouts might be occupying same place and overlapping so it seems missing check that ,it's a guess

Comment: Ahh yes thats looks to have fixed it. Cannot believe it was somthing so simple!! Many thanks for everyones help.